# Is there any sans-serif font that fully supports unicode-math?

Tags: fonts, unicode, unicode-math, sans-serif

As stated in the question title, is there any sans-serif font that fully supports the `unicode-math` package? Alternatively, is there a list that shows the different levels of support for (preferably many) different fonts (e.g. `Latin Modern Sans` has numbers, Latin letters and uppercase Greek letters, but no lowercase Greek letters and no/not all symbols)?

The fonts that are commonly advertised to fully work with `unicode-math` are `Latin Modern Math`, `Asana Math` and `XITS Math`. However, these are all serif fonts.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html and http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/math.html

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219392/state-of-unicode-math-typesetting-fonts?rq=1 is helpful? (Disclaimer: I provided an answer to that question.)

Comment: @Clément I know those sites, but they haven't been particularly helpful for discovering which fonts support unicode-math and to what extent they do it.

Comment: @cfr The comparison document is certainly helpful, but there are no sans-serif fonts to be found, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Of course not. It was an elaboration of @egreg's comment.

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematical_OpenType_typefaces) suggests these are the fonts which currently have a MATH table none of these is specifically sans serif although they should all have the sans latin alphabet and digits starting at [U+1d5a0](http://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/sans-serif.html)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The [GUST page](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math) linked from [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219414/) includes all of the ones Wikipedia lists, plus the TeX Gyre one offered by GUST which Wikipedia omits, and the GUST page provides additional information about the various options. Moreover, Wikipedia inaccurately lists the Latin Modern as Computer Modern.

Comment: Adding to Clèment's post: I have made good experinces with Arev and normally use it when I need excessive math support with a grotesque font. But AFAIK it does not support the full Unicode range.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm now doing one: https://github.com/firamath/firamath, which is based on FiraSans.

Here is a showcase (use beamer theme `metropolis`):

[image: showcase]

Of course, this work is far away from finished. For example, most of the relation symbols haven't been drawn. By the way, I'm a newbie to font design and creation, so if you have any suggestions, please tell me.

**Update:**

Now it's available in CTAN as [firamath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/firamath).

Comment: Great work — hope it goes well!

Comment: @stone-zeng Nice design and style!

Answer (score 8):

At the time of writing, there is no Unicode math font available which is sanserif across all of the range. There have been discussions about this (presentations and the like would benefit from availability, particularly for those people not in pure mathematics but using mathematical notation).

Answer (score 1):

The Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols unicode block defines 996 symbols: bold, italic, fraktur, serif, sans-serif, double-struck, latin/greek, script, etc, in various combinations.                       .

The MAS block definitions are `built-in`, separate to the font, and the MAS is also separate from the Latin and Greek blocks used for normal text. So that implies that any (math) font implementing the MAS, whether serif or sans, would have all those combinations,  like bold capital fraktur etc.

[image: The MAS]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{DejaVu Math}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\newcommand\mlatin{      \\       }
\newcommand\mgreek{    }
\newcommand\mdigits{    }

\begin{document}

{\normalsize Text mode (Noto Serif)}:
Plain characters here, abc ABC ΓΣΤ αβγ, then glyphs from unicode block Mathematical Alphamumeric Symbols:

\noindent\mlatin

\noindent\mgreek

\noindent\mdigits

{\normalsize Maths mode (DejaVu Math)}:
MAS glyphs:

\noindent$\mlatin \\
\mgreek \\
\mdigits$
\end{document}
```

So to do everything in sans, it should be a case of selecting a sans for the text mode, and in `unicode-math` mapping all the math styles to sans (range XX -> sf), I would expect. I'll do an experiment.

Comment: Is this LaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...?

Comment: @merrybot xelatex and lualatex, because those engines can handle unicode system fonts natively. `unicode-math` package calls `fontspec` in the background. Things can be done with legacy fonts under pdflatex, but the 127/256 character-limit of the font files involves doing a lot of extra work with encodings, multiple files, split files, conversions, mapping, virtual fonts, etc.  Unicode is easier (for me), plus the multiple math alphabets (20+) are predefined in Unicode, and one font file can contain all of them, plus the normal text, and more (XITS Math, Asana Math, etc).

Comment: @merrybot An example of mapping math alphabets might be of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340097/bold-sans-serif-math-font