# How to use Mathematical Pi font properly?

Tags: xetex, mathspec, adobe

I was asking the other day how to find certain fonts of a document. Well at last it was easy. I came to the Mathematical Pi LT Std font and ITC New Baskerville Std results and for that part, I was pleased because I finally managed to get those fonts.

So far, I have only used LaTeX for my documents and papers for the University and own projects and as most of us know, there are very few pleasant Math Fonts to use (at least for me). I have tried XeLaTeX and mathspec package to set the digits and latin to Baskerville and Greek to Mathematical Pi, but it turns out to be very clumsy when it comes to spacing and that stuff... and I ended up not liking the result. I have been checking the glyphs of Mathematical Pi and it contains a lot more than Greek Letters (obviously) but I don't know how to tell XeLaTeX to use for example the integral sign, relation signs, sums and everything else. I would like to know if there is any way to use Mathematical Pi font at full with any of the TeX systems and if that is not the case how to use that font other way, because I have been trying to use it in MS Word with its equation editor but I have not been successfull nor finding how to do it.

Can anyone help me with this?, I'm sure there has to be a way since I have found that font in many books. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Take a look at [this answer of mind](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166185/). Does the maths table for the font look like the MnSymbol one or the Latin Modern Math one? If the font is configured properly, you can use `unicode-math`. If not, well,  you have to stick with `mathspec`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think what you explain there is a little bit (much) technical for me, I have tried the code at the end of the post and some characters seem to work but others not. I suppose the font doesn't fit or I don't know how to do it properly... I think I'll have to deal with mathspec for a little bit more.

Comment: I meant just to look at the screenshots of the maths table. If you open the font you've got in something like fontforge, you can see if the maths table is set up properly (as it is for Latin Modern) or empty (as for MnSymbol). It will tell you whether `unicode-math` is a possibility or not. Or you could just try `unicode-math` and see if it complains ;).