# Lato fonts in math mode in lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math

Is it possible to use Lato font (http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/) in Math mode? (or a similar font)
I tried with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Lato Light}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Lato}
% \setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {Lato Light}
% \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Lato Bold}
% \setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Lato Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {Lato Light Italic}

\begin{document}

some math

\begin{equation}
    \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} f(a)\alpha = \sum_{i=0} g_{i} \sqrt{h_{i}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

but the summation symbol looks too small and the square root symbols are messed up.

I've also tried using `pdflatex` with the `mathastext` package but it doesn't work nicely with the Greek letters or the math symbols.

Comment: unicode-math needs the main font to have a unicode MATH table which I don't think this does, you could try the mathspec interfaces instead, that is designed to use opentype text fonts in math

Comment: Not unless it has a MATH table. See my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152714/possible-to-use-mnsymbol-with-luatex/166185?s=1|2.8553#166185 for a detailed explanation.